# mail received at sendmail has relay=localhost [[UNIX: localhost]] causing check_rcpt to say Relaying denied

Tags: email, sendmail

I have setup my local sendmail as a Smart Host and trying to relay all incoming mails to a mail server.

However, whenever i try to send a mail to an internet mail address, getting the following error:

```
ruleset=check_rcpt, arg1=<chingupt1@gmail.com>, relay=localhost [[UNIX: localhost]], reject=550 5.7.1 <chingupt1@gmail.com>... Relaying denied
```

I debugged the sendmail configuration file and found that this rule fails as its receiving the  client_addr as localhost and client_resolve is resolving to NULL. and client_name is getting set to client_name which it tries to resolve into some hostname.

My hostname is a.b.c
its converting it to localhost.b.c

Logs of check_rcpt:

```
Relay_ok           input: < email1 @ gmail . com >
rewrite: RHS $&{client_addr} => "localhost"
rewritten as: localhost
rewritten as: [ localhost ]
rewrite: RHS $&{client_resolve} => "(NULL)"
rewritten as: < >
rewrite: RHS $&{client_name} => "localhost"
rewritten as: < @ > localhost
rewritten as: < ? > localhost . b . c
rewritten as: < ? > localhost . b . c
Relay_ok         returns: < ? > localhost . b . c
rewritten as: O $| < ? > localhost . b . c
rewritten as: $# error $@ 5 . 7 . 1 $: "550 Relaying denied"
Basic_check_rcpt returns: $# error $@ 5 . 7 . 1 $: "550 Relaying denied"
rewritten as: $# error $@ 5 . 7 . 1 $: "550 Relaying denied"
check_rcpt       returns: $# error $@ 5 . 7 . 1 $: "550 Relaying denied"
```

In sendmail.cf file, i have set the SMART_HOST to my mail server, yet its getting set to localhost.

Can anyone please provide some pointers on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

See ["Anti-Spam Configuration Control" in cf/README](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/anti_spam.html) file in Sendmail distribution.
IMHO It suggests that the following access table entry should fix you problem.

/etc/mail/access entry (file requires compilation with makemap):

```
connect:[UNIX:localhost]  RELAY
```

If it does not work (as you reported) then try

```
connect:localhost  RELAY
```

Comment: didn't work. Tried all possible configurations present on the net, still it remains the same.

Comment: Ask your question at news:comp.mail.sendmail. IMHO It looks like a some subtle bug in your configuration or a bug in senmdail (documentation).

Comment: It seems after looking at cf/m4/proto.m4 that `connect:localhost  RELAY` in access should work. Ask at news:comp.mail.sendmail if it is side effects free.